# Can I submit an html-like link to Twitter API

Tags: api, twitter

I am trying to submit a tweet to the Twitter API (v1.1) that looks like this:

```
here is a tweet link <a href="http://bit.ly/path">http://mylinktext.com</a>
```

Right now, if you submit a raw link, twitter automatically substitutes its t.co link wrapper. Can I use my own? I don't care if Twitter wraps my shortener too (two layers of redirection).

EDIT: Can I submit a URL entity via post to the Twitter API?

Answer (score 1):

Links posted to and from Twitter will come out as http://t.co/ regardless.

Read this for some more clarification:

[FAQs about Twitter's Link Service (http://t.co)](https://support.twitter.com/articles/109623-faqs-about-twitter-s-link-service-http-t-coresr)

> Because of the reasons listed above, Twitter will shorten URLs you
>   post on Twitter.com. You cannot opt out of link shortening.

Comment: sure. I'm ok with Twitter shortening my bit.ly link. But I want the t.co to forward to bit.ly to forward to the displayed link. Is this possible?